# Gaussian elimination for lower triangular matrix

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, gaussian

I have got a a trouble with Gaussian elimination for lower triangular matrix, I can't imagine how the loops should work right here. I tried to run loop backwards, but it didn't help. For now all I've got is Gaussian elimination for upper triangular matrix.

```
For[k = 1, k <= size - 1, k++,
     For[i = k + 1, i <= size, i++,
      If[tab[[k]][[k]] != 0,
       help = tab[[i]][[k]]/tab[[k]][[k]];
       For[j = k, j <= size, j++,
        tab[[i]][[j]] = tab[[i]][[j]] - help*tab[[k]][[j]];
        identity[[i]][[j]] = identity[[i]][[j]] - help*tab[[k]][[j]]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
```

Can someone help me please?

@edit

I made loops like that

```
For[k = size, k > 1, k--,
 For[i = k - 1, i >= 1, i--,
```

And it seems like it works, but now I've got a problem, because these two loops doesn't give invertible matrix.

Example Matrix:

```
[ 3 4 2 ]
[ 5 5 5 ]
[ 1 5 3 ]
```

Output for upper-diagonal

```
[3   4   2  ]
[0 -5/3 5/3 ]
[0   0   6  ]
```

Output for Identity-Matrix

```
  [1    0      0  ]
  [-5 -17/3 -10/3 ]  
  [-1   -5    -4  ]
```

And now, when I run loop for lower-diagonal, the output for it is not correct. It doesn't divide the main diagonal

Comment: Have you seen [`RowReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RowReduce.html).  You may also want to have a look at the [Matrices and Linear Algebra](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MatricesAndLinearAlgebra.html) guide which links to many other linear algebra guides.

Comment: Note that the `For` loop in mathematica is a little bit different from C. In C/C++, the increment of index is executed after loop operations while in the code you wrote, before any inside-loop operations the index is incremented.

Comment: show some example small matrices and the expected results. Its not clear if you have a coding problem or a problem with linear algebra (Gauss elimination on an upper triangular matrix doesn't do anything)

Comment: @agentp, done. But i thought that if i'll make Gauss elimination on upper triangular matrix and lower one, it will make an invertible matrix, no?

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant the *input* was upper triangular. shouldn't that be `identity[[i]][[j]] = identity[[i]][[j]] - help*identity[[k]][[j]]` ?

Comment: Well I don't think so, if im wrong correct me please.

Comment: But as I said, the problem is already in lower-triangular, because it doesn't divide the main diagonal, while in upper-triangular it works fine and diagonal is beeing divided.

Comment: `tab` and `identity` really form a single augmented matrix, so the same row operations must be allied to each.    I'd actually create the augmented matrix as `aug = Transpose@Flatten[{Transpose@tab, IdentityMatrix@Length@tab}, 1]` and work with that.

Comment: I made something like that

Comment: I made something like that 'code' tab = Transpose[tab], identity = Transpose[identity], after that made same loop, which is at the top of post, and it still gives wrong result at the end :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I found the problem, but I don't know how could I solve that - upper-triangular-matrix-loop works fine, but the problem is with lower triangular one, it doesn't divide elements on diagonal.